# How to display mask in text input control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to make such a thing happen so that the input box shows underscore/underline right when you click the input box and then as you type the dashes keep getting replaced by characters.

Like in this case for a phone no. there was a 10-digit underscore/underline already there as I click on the input box and as I fill in the contact no. the characters replace the underscore/underline.

[image]

Like there is this 'Mobile' input box, I want it to work in the following way:

- It should show blank (white) when idle but when clicked it should show a ten character underscores/underlines/dashes which depicts the 10-digit phone no. is required to be filled in.

  e.g. Mobile +91(0): ____________________
- Then, as I start typing in the dashes should start to get replaced by the numbers typed. Like if 2 numbers/digits are typed there should be 8 dashes following the 2 numbers/digits that were typed.

  e.g. Mobile +91(0): 98________________
- And this should keep on going like 5 numbers down it should look like what follows

  e.g. Mobile +91(0): 99887__________

and so on. As all the numbers/digits have been filled in the input box the dashes totally get replaced by the typed in numbers, which shows the user that all 10-digits have been filled in and no number has been left out.

Comment: The title of the question does not correspond to its content. This is not about placeholders at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery **jqxMaskedInput**

> jqxMaskedInput represents a jQuery input widget which uses a mask to
>   distinguish between proper and improper user input. You can define
>   phone number, ssn, zip code, dates, etc. masks by setting the
>   jqxMaskedInput mask property.

Here is the link

http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxmaskedinput/jquery-masked-input-getting-started.htm

Comment: can you please further help me in validation of the jquery input mask field? im not able to apply any html5/jquery validation on it.. the form just submit it even if the field is empty